# Understanding the PercentTrue primitive output in featuretools

Tags: featuretools

I've been playing with the [predict-appointment-noshow notebook tutorial](https://github.com/Featuretools/predict-appointment-noshow) and I'm confused by the output of the `PERCENT_TRUE` primitive.

My understanding is that after feature generation, a column like `locations.PERCENT_TRUE(appointments.sms_received)` gives the percent of rows for which `sms_received` is True, given a single location, which was defined as its own `Entity` earlier. I'd expect that column to be the same for all rows of a single location, because that's what it was conditioned on, but I'm not finding that to be the case. Any ideas why?

Here's an example from that notebook data to demonstrate:

```
>>> fm.loc[fm.neighborhood == 'HORTO', 'locations.PERCENT_TRUE(appointments.sms_received)'].describe()

count 144.00
mean 0.20
std 0.09
min 0.00
25% 0.20
50% 0.23
75% 0.26
max 0.31
Name: locations.PERCENT_TRUE(appointments.sms_received), dtype: float64
```

Even though the location is restricted to just `'HORTO'`, the column ranges from 0.00-0.31. How is this being calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a result of using cutoff times when calculating this feature matrix.

In this example, we are making predictions for every appointment at the time the appointment is scheduled. The feature `locations.PERCENT_TRUE(appointments.sms_received)` therefore is calculated at a specific time given by the cutoff times. It is calculating for each appointment "the percentage of appointments at this location received an an sms prior to the `scheduled_time`"

That construction is necessary to prevent the leakage of future information into the prediction for that row at that time. If we were calculated `PERCENT_TRUE` using the whole dataset, we'd necessarily be using information from appointments that hadn't yet happened, which isn’t valid for predictive modeling.

If you instead want to make the predictions after all of the data is known, all you have to do is remove the `cutoff_time` argument to the `ft.dfs` call:

```
fm, features = ft.dfs(entityset=es,
                      target_entity='appointments',
                      agg_primitives=['count', 'percent_true'],
                      trans_primitives=['weekend', 'weekday', 'day', 'month', 'year'],
                      max_depth=3,
                      approximate='6h',
                      # cutoff_time=cutoff_times[20000:],
                      verbose=True)
```

Now you can see that the feature is the same when we condition on a specific location

```
fm.loc[fm.neighborhood == 'HORTO', 'locations.PERCENT_TRUE(appointments.sms_received)'].describe()
count   175.00
mean      0.32
std       0.00
min       0.32
25%       0.32
50%       0.32
75%       0.32
max       0.32
```

You can read more about how Featuretools handles time in the [documentation](https://docs.featuretools.com/automated_feature_engineering/handling_time.html).

Comment: Ok, so if they're calculated based on a certain time, the first row chronologically will always be 0.00 for this field then? Because there are no previous instances of an SMS being received? If so, is there a way to seed this with prior information about initial sms_received rates, for example?

Comment: that's correct. not clear to me how we could seed it with initial information. if you have additional data to calculate that value, you could provide it as part of the entity set. 

Another option is to remove the first appointments from the list of cutoff times. The data from those appointments will be used, but there won't be a row in the resulting feature matrix corresponding to those appointments